# Cufflinks how to use connectgaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

In python `plotly` you can use `connectgaps = true` in case there are datapoints missing. Plotly will plot lines between them.

My question is how does that work with cufflinks. It is based on `plotly` so I would assume that it should work as well. Does someone has an example how missing data is connected in a graph with cufflinks?

So this is not working for me:

```
df.iplot(kind=‘line’, connectgaps = True)
```

Thanks!
Amir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now.

`df.iplot(kind=‘line’, connectgaps = True)`